# Oracle APEX Interactive Grid custom action database update

Tags: oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5.1

I have an interactive grid with custom action defined on it. What I am trying to do is loop through the grid, grabbing all the selected records, then loop through the records and update a single database field for each record, setting it to 0.

I am using the following code to loop through the records, grabbing record ID:

```
view=apex.region("myGrid").widget().interactiveGrid("getViews","grid");

if (view.supports.edit)
{
    model=view.model;
    records=view.getSelectedRecords();
    if(records.length>0)
    {
        for(i=0;i< records.length; i++)
       {

            $record_id= model.getValue(records[i], "RECORD_ID");
            //update the database here UPDATE TABLE1 SET Flag=0 WHERE RECORD_ID=$record_id
        }
    }
}
```

what is the best way to perform an update from here?

Comment: Is the table different from the table used in the interactive grid?

Comment: in the interactive grid I am using multiple tables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Had a pretty similair situation a bit back. I wanted to go through an IG and change one column for every selected record. I set up a Dynamic action triggered on a button, and had it run the following Javascript, and after the javascript set up another tru action for submit page, otherwise you still need to save manually. This was my solution:

```
    var g = apex.region('MY_INTERACTIVE_GRID').widget().interactiveGrid('getViews','grid');  
    var r = g.getSelectedRecords();  
    for(i = 0; i < r.length; i++) {   
    g.model.setValue(r[i], 'MY_COLLUMN', 'VALUE_I_WANT');
}
```

Hope this helps, a lot of the solutions I found didnt work for me, this one worked(Im on 18.2)

Comment: would that work if my IG is populated from a collection?

Comment: This method only changes the values in the IG as long as they are marked as editable. Your save might not work but you can write a custom plsql procedure for that.